# Transposing Text Files

Tags: text, notepad

I have over 20,000 records that are being exported from a program that look like this:

```
Parent   : 000691195
CUSTNO   : 115225036-AD
COMPANY  : BROOK FURNITURE RENTAL
ADDRESS1 : 100 N FIELD DR
city     : LAKE FOREST
STATE    : IL
ZIP      : 600452580

Parent   : 000691195
CUSTNO   : 116952265-AD
COMPANY  : BROOK FURNITURE RENTAL
ADDRESS1 : 100 N FIELD DR STE 220
city     : LAKE FOREST
STATE    : IL
ZIP      : 600452598
```

I need to transpose them into usable columns and rows, but I have no IDEA how to get it to work from the text file. I have looked at some answers in how to replace the carriage return to a comma but the last piece of data need to NOT have a comma after it to indicate the end of the row and some of the ADDRESS1 fields are empty anyway.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Format data please

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what you mean by that comment?

Comment: I tried adding an image but I am not allowed to yet...

Comment: Notice at right sidebar: `How to edit`, `How to format`, when you make post. You may add 4 whitespaces at the beginning of line  or select text and press `CTRL+K`

Comment: This feels like a daunting task to be accomplished within a text editor. Do you know any programming language you could use to write a script?

Comment: See my answer below, it was not as hard as it seems, I just needed to figure out how and where to replace blank lines and carriage returns and then add new carriage returns where needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can complete that task by writing small script, for example, in perl.
Perl is designed to work with text transformations better than other languages.

```
Perl - Practical Extraction and Reporting Language
```

If you do not know any programming language. You may hire freelancer that may complete that task at [upwork.com](http://upwork.com) or similar site

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out - it is actually a combination of a couple of different answers here in StackOverflow.

First I needed to replace ALL of the carriage returns with "^" this would allow me to open the delimited file later without worrying about commas in Company names.

Next where the one line ended and the next began, there was the text ^Parent so I replaced it with \r\nParent and that gave me each one a new line.

Finally I deleted all of the extraneous "header" information and that left me with just the data I needed.